# How to use Direct Path in OCCI?

Tags: oracle, occi, direct-path

From the OCCI documentation https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/toc.htm, I cannot find an obvious API to use DirectPath, do I need call OCI api directly in the OCCI application?